# Typescript exclude module import code from output

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Looks like typings for common projects are wrapped in a module. For example, react & react-dom.

So i need to use like `import * as React from 'react'` for typescript to know that React exists.

I am using Typescript for browser code-base and i would to compile all my ts files into a single js file.

Is there any way i can just exclude the module imports from output file?

I use latest Typescript version.

Comment: Hey @mamu, any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! (if you're using webpack)

Here's how I do it in`webpack.config.js`:

```js
...
   externals: {
      "react": "React",
      "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
  },
...
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way i can just exclude the module imports from output file

Don't use `--outFile`. There are other reasons for my dislike as well : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

With *modules* you can tell the module loader (e.g. webpack) to exclude a particular module from the bundle it builds as you might be using it from e.g some CDN.

Comment: I mean i would like to exclude 'var React = require('react');' lines from the output file, without some module resolver it is going to error in the browser. I would just like to concat all project files and use.

Comment: ` I would just like to concat all project files and use ` Use `react` *global* version of the definition (instead of the module version)